# As Single As It Gets

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could you explain the meaning of "As Single As It Gets"?
Does "As Single As It Gets" mean "very lonely"? Is it used to emphasize "loneliness"? (just like in "as good as it gets").

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the source for this to your question please?  eg a link to where you read it?

Comment: For example: I'm not going to say I'm as single as it gets, but sometimes it feels that way. At first it's rough getting into the motions of not depending on the other person, but you learn to enjoy it. https://www.theodysseyonline.com/love-single

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a couple of ways we could read "As single as it gets" in that context.

> 1. Never having any kind of sexual relationship with anyone, even casually
> 2. Suffering the negative consequences of being single in the most extreme way - eg loneliness.  (your suggested interpretation)
> 3. Fitting the stereotype of a single person, ie the expectations (whatever they might be) about how single people think, live or behave.

So, when the author says "I'm not going to say I'm as single as it gets, but sometimes it feels that way." she might mean that (following the options above)

> 1) She has sex occasionally (or perhaps frequently) but isn't in a relationship
>
> 2) She sometimes feels lonely, but not so much that she is depressed, for example
>
> 3) She doesn't feel like she fits the stereotype of a single woman (whatever that might be).

There could well be other interpretations you could think of.  The problem is that "single" is a complex concept, with many characteristics, and we're being asked to choose one (or more) of those characteristics and take it/them to the extreme to get "As single as it gets".  We're going to tend to have to guess.

Comment: Whatever it's intended to mean, it's a quirky 'gradabilisation' of an ungradable (in this case classifying) adjective.